# fmin_cg giving nexpected error

Tags: python, scipy

just learned gradient desc. algo and i tried to implement it, input is set of cordinates on 2D plane, and aim is to predict the line that passes through most of given input points.
using python, i wrote :

```
def cost( theta, data ):
    X, y = data[:, 0], data[:, 1]
    m = shape(X)[0]
    y    = y.reshape(m, 1)
    X = c_[ones((m, 1)), X]

    J = X.dot(theta) - y
    J = J.T.dot(J) / (m)
    # print(J[0, 0])
    return J

def gradDesc(theta, data):
    X = data[:, 0]
    y  = data[:, 1]
    m = shape(X)[0]
    X = c_[ones((m, 1)), X]
    y    = y.reshape(m, 1)
    hypo = X.dot(theta)
    grad = X.T.dot(hypo - y)/m
    # print(grad)
    return grad

def run(theta, data ):
    result  = scipy.optimize.fmin_cg( f = cost, fprime=gradDesc, x0=theta,  \
                                        args = (data), maxiter=50, disp=False, full_output=True )
    theta = result[0]
    minCost = result[1]
    return theta, minCost

def main():
    data = genfromtxt('in.txt', delimiter=',')
    theta = zeros((2, 1))
    # plot_samples(data)
    run(theta, data)
```

i tried using fmin_cg() to minimize cost, but one of its parameters 'args' causes an error : 
line 282, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
TypeError: gradDesc() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given

in docs i read that args is the list of params passed to f and fprime other than the one to be altered to minimize f, which here is data. need help to know where i am going wrong ..

full code : http://ideone.com/E22yzl

Comment: Try adding a comma in the brackets: `args = (data,)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extra arguments need to be a tuple. If you mean to have a single parameter called `data`, you need to construct a one-element tuple `(data,)` -- notice the comma. This is not the same as `(data)`, where brackets are effectively ignored.

Example:

```
>>> def f(x, data):
...    return (x - data.sum())**2
... 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.asarray([1., 2., 3.])
>>> fmin_cg(f, x0=11., args=(data,))
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 2
         Function evaluations: 15
         Gradient evaluations: 5
array([ 6.])
```

Comment: thanx for help @ev-br, after removing this bug i get another error, which is probably due to grad being returned as a 2 D array [[ ]], while it should be returned as [], any suggestions how i could get gradDesc() to return grad as [], the error : line 1156, in _minimize_cg
    deltak = numpy.dot(gfk, gfk)
ValueError: shapes (2,4) and (2,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)